# linq subselect causing out of memory error

Tags: c#, linq

The Version field subselect in the where caluse is causing an out of memory error. If I remove it then the query works fine. The user profile table has multiple entries for each version and I only want the most recent in the final query results. Any ideas on how to make this query work without getting an out of memory error?

```
var x = (from p in userProfileRepo.All
                         join u1 in userRepo.All on p.USERID equals u1.USERID
                         join u2 in userRepo.All on p.LAST_MODIFIED_BY equals u2.USERID
                         join a in attrRepo.All on new { p.GROUP_NAME, p.PROFILE_NAME } equals new { a.GROUP_NAME, a.PROFILE_NAME } into attrJoin
                         from sub_a in attrJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where p.VERSION == (from up in userProfileRepo.All
                                             where up.GROUP_NAME == p.GROUP_NAME
                                             && up.PROFILE_NAME == p.PROFILE_NAME
                                             && up.USERID == p.USERID
                                             group up by up.VERSION into g
                                             select g.Max(t => t.VERSION)).FirstOrDefault()
                         select new
                         {
                             GroupName = p.GROUP_NAME,
                             Author = u1.FIRSTNAME + @"\" + u1.LASTNAME,
                             LastModifiedBy = u2.FIRSTNAME + @"\" + u2.LASTNAME,
                             ProfileName = p.PROFILE_NAME,
                             Version = p.VERSION,
                             GroupName2 = (sub_a == null ? "" : sub_a.GROUP_NAME),
                             AttrName = (sub_a == null ? "" : sub_a.ATTR_NAME),
                             AttrDisplayName = (sub_a == null ? "" : sub_a.ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME),
                             AttrValue = (sub_a == null ? "" : sub_a.ATTR_VALUE),
                             Visible = (sub_a == null ? "" : sub_a.VISIBLE)
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: Does running the sub-select query by itself cause an error?

Comment: The sub-select has a where clause that requires the data coming from the outer query, but the table in the sub-select is the same table used in the outer query so yes, I can query that table with filters just fine because I do that in the outer query.